# Eclipse automatically refresh imported directory

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to refresh automatically folder that was imported into project?

My usual procedure is to create project, then select "Import->File System" where I select existing directory (call it directory "ABC") and then select Advanced and check "Create links in workspace" in order to avoid copying files. And that works great. However if I add files externally (outside of eclipse) in the directory "ABC" these files are not added automatically to project. So basically if there are too many files I just remove directory and add it again to get new files.

Question: Is it possible for Eclipse to automatically add files externally added to directory?

Thanks everyone in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you checked the **Workspace** preference page for its automatic refresh options?

Comment: I have both checked on "Refresh using native hooks or pooling" and "Refresh on access"